# Mybatis-Guice bootstrapping help required

Tags: guice, mybatis

I am trying to use the MyBatis-Guice DI feature, but i do not know how to get started.

I have prior experience to using factory classes to get MyBatis Mappers, but i simply do not know where to start on Guice.

For example, i have written the following codes, which i am not sure how this gets picked up by Guice, if ever.

```
public class MyOwnBatisModule {

    protected void initialize() {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new XMLMyBatisModule() {
            @Override
            protected void initialize() {
                setEnvironmentId("sos");
                setClassPathResource("sg/java/bus/dao/mybatis-config.xml");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

After i have written this, how do i get Guice to bootstrap or load this in order to initialize the resources and i can start using my Mappers?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use the Injector you just created to create your instances:

injector.getInstance(MyClass.class)

But from looking at your code, I would suggest that you start with some Basic DI/Guice examples (getting started) and watch the clip on the guice homepage.

Afterwards, you probably will use @Inject to get the Mappings injected where you need them.

Comment: Thanks Jan. I have come across this, http://www.slideshare.net/simonetripodi/mybatis-googleguice, does it mean that what i need to do next is simply annotate @Inject on my mapper where i need it, and it will automatically get injected?

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind, that injection only works when Guice creates the instance (via getInstance() for example), it wont work when you use "new" to create the instance yourself. Did you watch the introdution video?

Comment: Hi Jan, no i didn't watch it, shoot me haha. I will watch it, do you have the link please?